# Autofs mount nfs issues

Tags: centos, autofs, nfs

I'm having some issues getting autofs to work properly on a new Centos 5.5 installation.
Please find Exports from my storage servers:

```
/san/files  *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/san/mail   *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

On my client my auto.master looks as follows:

```
/home   /etc/auto.home --timeout=60
/net    -hosts
```

auto.home:

```
vmail -fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid,rw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/san/mail
```

I'm not wanting to use NIS however my bigger picture is to have a fall over nfs server however at the present time im just working with the single server.

I can manually mount the nfs share perfectly fine using "mount -t nfs xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/san/mail /home/vmail" (when mountpoint exists Obv)

permissions on /home:

```
# ls -shalt /home
total 8.0K
   0 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May  3 08:51 .
8.0K drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K May  3 08:51 ..
```

The problem is when trying to go to /home/vmail i get the following:

```
# ls -shalt /home/vmail
ls: /home/vmail: No such file or directory
```

running "automount -vf" I get the following output:

```
Starting automounter version 5.0.1-0.rc2.143.el5_5.6, master map auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.01
mounted indirect on /home with timeout 60, freq 15 seconds
mounted indirect on /net with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
attempting to mount entry /home/vmail
lookup(program): lookup for vmail failed
failed to mount /home/vmail
```

Using /net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/san/mail/ works!

Please help with any pointers? I'm at a dead end now.

Comment: Does it help to `mkdir /home/vmail` ?

Comment: no my understanding of autofs should create this folder dynamically, when automount is running i am unable to create the directory.

Comment: Oh OK. Sorry, it's been over 10 years since I worked with automount ....

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled, BTW? SElkinux under Centos 5.x tend to be pretty strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lookup(program) means automount thinks your map is an executable, does it have the executable bit set?

lookup(file) is what you should be seeing

See http://www.squarebox.co.uk/cgi-squarebox/manServer/automount.8.